# iOS app does not have a Build directory with .app in - for binary upload

Tags: ios, binary, .app

I have an iOS app which I need to upload the binary of. From what I could find online, I have to `ZIP` the `.app` folder and upload that.

Problem is I cannot find my `.app` directory. In my other apps I do find it. But in this specific one, there is no `Build` directory whatsoever.

Must I set it in my Target or somewhere for it to create that folder?
(This is in Xcode 4.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the app appear in the Products folder for your project (should be at the bottom of the project file/folder list in the left column)? If it does, right click on the .app file and choose the Open in Finder option. Zip the Application file and you should be fine.

Comment: Looks like Xcode made a deep path in it's own folder. I.e. `Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myappname_withsomeID/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myappname.app`

Answer (score 0):

If this is an app that you can run on a device, choose Build > Archive. The Organizer window will open, and now you can select and "share" the archive.

Otherwise, open the Preferences window and, under Locations, click the arrow next to the Derived Data pathname. Your build folder is usually inside the derived data folder for this project.